# Is there a way to play all the videos in my subscribed channels?

Tags: youtube

I'd like to be able to just go to https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions and press a button and play all the videos in my subscriptions. As it is I have to go through the list, look and see which ones I might like, press watch later, go to watch later, order the videos the way I want and then go to watch later and press play. I'm totally ok with watching them in the feed order instead of the order I want, I'll just press next if I don't like a video.

This has been asked before but it was [8 years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/791383/how-do-i-play-new-videos-from-my-youtube-subscriptions-as-a-playlist). There is one answer but it involves a complicated setup ("This is done using Google Sheets for interface, Google Script + Youtube API v3 for executing and scheduling" plus a fair bit of instructions for how to use it).

Comment: hey, could you link to that other answer from 8 years ago, and explain why it doesn't work for you today?

Comment: Done @MarcusMüller

Comment: thank you, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

'[PocketTube'](https://pockettube.io/) for Chrome might help you: you'll see the 'Play All' button in the top left corner above the list of the latest videos of your https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions page.
The extension is also available for Firefox, but this particular feature doesn't work in the Firefox version AFAICS.